# What is the daily limit on the number of images Watson Visual Recognition.

Tags: image, max, limit, visual-recognition

What is the daily limit on the number of images that could be processed using Watson Visual Recognition. Free plan on the doc shows 250. Can we upload more on a Standard plan ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard plan will allow you to upload more then the free version of 250.

Just be aware that training events are the most expensive. So try to batch upload with zips.

Comment: Thanks Simon. While I log into Bluemix VR , it only says the pricing for events & training but it did not specify how many images could be uploaded per day on a Standard plan as opposed to Free which was 250 per day. Hence was the question..

Answer (score 1):

With the standard plan by default you can process 25,000 events per day. If you would like to do more you can  submit a bluemix support request asking for that to be lifted.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Is there any email id I need to send to do more image uploads. Also by mentioning events did you also mean image uploads !!

Comment: Yes, by events I meant images.... For official pricing details, you should consult https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/visual-recognition/

Comment: To request the limit be lifted on your standard plan API key, you should submit a Bluemix support ticket - https://support.ng.bluemix.net/supportticket/?app=technicalsupport&index=5